# ASP.NET localization: Do changes in resx files results in sessions being killed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, localization

My observations in my development setup:

- I have a running ASP.NET application that displays localized resources from resx-files.
- I change the resx-files while the app is running
- Upon page refresh, the changed resources are correctly displayed in the ui
- The session was killed by the refresh

I am using ASP.NET MVC3.
I am using InProc sessions.
I am running the application through VisualStudio 2010 on IIS Express.

Is the above behavior generally true, or only on my development setup:

- Does a change in resx-files always trigger the recompilation of the application and consequently kill all InProc sessions?
- Is this also the case on "production" IIS?
- Is this somehow dependent on some configuration?
- Does switching session state to stateserver or sqlserver solve this problem. Is it then possible to change resx-files while the app is running, having the changes reflected in the ui on reload and still preserving session state?

Comment: If you need to change the resources on the fly, you really need to sue something other resx files. they're designed to be static, hence changing them causes a rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it looks like the session is cleared, since the cache needs to be re-created with the new values.

There is some discussion about it here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1091924.aspx/1

Looks like you might have to work around it.